# php mysql pagination active class

Tags: php, pagination

I want to be able to add a active class to a pagination so I know which page I am on but am unsure how to add it into the current code I have, below is what I currently have

```
$per_page=6;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {

$page = $_GET["page"];

}

else {

$page=1;

}

// Page will start from 0 and Multiple by Per Page
$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY COLUMNNAME ASC LIMIT $start_from, $per_page"))

// Count the total records
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//Using ceil function to divide the total records on per page
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

//Going to first page
echo "<div class='btn-group' style='margin:0 auto;display:table;'>";
echo "<br><br><center><a href='view-all-customers.php?page=1' class='btn btn-primary float-button- 
light' style='color:#FFFFFF;padding:6px 15px;'>".'First Page'."</a>";

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {

echo "<a href='view-all-customers.php?page=".$i."' class='btn btn-primary float-button-light' 
style='color:#FFFFFF;padding:6px 15px;'>".$i."</a>";
};
// Going to last page
echo "<a href='view-all-customers.php?page=$total_pages' class='btn btn-primary float-button-light' 
style='color:#FFFFFF;padding:6px 15px;'>".'Last Page'."</a></center>";
echo "</div>";
```

I have left out the data table rows as thought it's better to show the pagination coding more than showing the table tr and td rows outputting the data

Answer (score 1):

```
//check page and add active class

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
    $isActive = '';
    if($i == $page){
        $isActive = 'active';
    }

    echo "<a href='view-all-customers.php?page=".$i."' class='".$isActive."btn btn-primary float-button-light' style='color:#FFFFFF;padding:6px 15px;'>".$i."</a>";
};
```